# How to set a type to Kendo Grid Filter?

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

How to set a type to filter on the columns, while they being generated?
 *'string', 'int', 'date' etc?* 
Is it even possible? If type of our column is 'date', not to show 'Starts with', 'Contains' etc... 
If it's integer, to show 'Greater Then' etc...

```js
columns: {
      title: "Test",
      field: "Test2",
      width: "120px",
      hidden: false,
      type: "number",
```

Comment: have you looked at the documentation? See this section for further help http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable . If you need an example I am sure I can provide one for you but would need to know a bit more about your specific scenario to provide a meaningful example to you.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding

Comment: Found it, you have to set the data type in the dataSource's schema.model